# Разбиение программы на логические части. Как лучше?

Tags: проектирование

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!
Вопрос касательно проектирования программных систем.
Есть один принцип, что надо разбивать программу на множество логических единиц. Если это даже относится к `JavaScript` программам. Делаю я одну немаленькую программу, и начал разбивать ее на логические единицы. И получилось так, что некоторые JS-файлы у меня по 5 строчек, и разводиться начало этих файлов тьма тьмущая.
Ну так вот и вопрос: *хорошо ли это*?

**UPD1**:
По поводу логических единиц. Я разделил примерно так. Есть одна страница. На этой странице есть несколько элементов. Каждый такой элемент - один файл JS. Есть составные элементы. Каждая составная этого элемента -  тоже отдельный файл (поместил в туже папку). Есть в элементах области данных. Эти области состоят из запроса на сервер, модели, шаблона. И это все тоже разделил на отдельные составляющие. Все окна поместил в папку `windows`, все компоненты и составляющие для составных компонентов, поместил в папку `components`, любые вещи, связанные с данными (хранение, отправки запросов на взятие данных), поместил в папку `data`. Ну и остальное.

**UPD2**:
[image: страница]

вот организация:

[image]

Тут указано расположение файлов для верхнего компонента. Все остальное по аналогии.

Comment: Что вы называете логической единицей ( для случая в 5 строк )?

Comment: А для случая в пять строк - это типа `DataStore`.

Comment: Запостите описание некого окна и то как вы расположили файлы этого окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я-бы как-то примерно так:

```
from22
|-model.js
|-data.js
|-window.js
|-info_block/
   |-component.js
   |-ava.js
   |-name.js
   |-btn.js
|-mega_table/
   |-component.js
```

model.js/data.js должны находится в той папке - к чему относятся...

Прим: Окно состоит из Формы и Визуализатора. Валидатор полей - находится в папке формы.

Пояснение ( считаем что весь код уникален, и применим только к данной форме, и потому храниться так ):

Есть форма ( form22 ) выглядит она как окно. Окно формируется по некому алгоритму ( window.js ), принимает данные в неком формате ( data.js ) и работает согласно какой-то модели ( model.js ). В окне есть 2 компонента: информация ( info_block ) и некая таблица ( mega_table ). Компонент информации состоит из 3х частей: аватарка ( ava.js ), кнопки ( btn.js ), имя ( name.js ).

Если какой-то компонент имеет повторяемость, а так-же имеет свои model.js и data.js, то он храниться так:

```
Некая глобальная папка с компонентами
|-component_abcd
   |-component.js
   |-model.js
   |-data.js
```

Comment: Не ясен ответ. Можно по подробнее? И, если можно, применимо к моему примеру в вопросе.

Comment: Ещё поподробнее?

Comment: Ухты! У вас, определенно, опыт большой! Надо принять к сведению ваш метод! Я пытался сделать что-то похожее, что советовал автор книги по JS, той, что с носорогом. Поэтому называл файлы JS подобным образом. И, я верно понял, что для одного окна создаем файл, туда забрасываем from22.js |-model.js |-data.js ... ... и т.д.?

Comment: И еще. Я так понял, что мое разбивание на такое количество файлов - нормально, и даже правильно?   
Ухты! По вашему методу даже легче ориентироваться в программе! Ваш ответ ОЧЕНЬ хорош и полезен! Спасибо!

Comment: Была опечатка... Для формы - создаём папку, в папку заносим всё что определяет эту форму... Если что-то сложное  или хотя-бы может быть сложным ( компонент ) то заводим вложенную папку, в которой и храним сие.... Как-то так)

Чуть позже - попробую привести структуру большого приложения с описанием...

Answer (score 0):

Может быть стоит обратить внимание на паттерны проектирования? Это избавит от необходимости велосипедоизобретательства. 
Начать можно [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). А продолжить [тут](http://www.books.ru/books/patterny-proektirovaniya-850800/).

Comment: Это прекрасная книга! Вот только иногда терзают сомнения, правильно ли я использую свои знания конструкций велосипедов. Поэтому и спросил.

Comment: Причём здесь проектирование классов? Если речь о организации хранения файлов?